# Finding $E[Z^2\Phi(Z)]$ using law of the unconscious statistician

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Question:

> Random Variable $Z$ follows a standard normal distribution with c.d.f. $\Phi$.
>
> Find $E[Z^2\Phi(Z)]$ using the law of the unconscious statistician.

I am thinking of using some substitution to work it out, for example, using $\phi'(z)=-z\phi(z)$ can help to solve $E[Z\Phi(Z)]$, but I don’t know how to apply this trick for finding out $E[Z^2\Phi(Z)]$.

Comment: Do you know that $\Phi(Z)$ follows a $Uniform(0,1)$
 distribution?

Comment: Also, note that the form $F(x)f(x)$ is nice to integrate because $f(x) = F'(x)$.

Comment: So you might want to consider an integration by parts approach.

Comment: Yes, I have tried integration by parts using and transform dz to d (ϕ(z)): -∫z Φ(z) d(ϕ(z)), but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: How about doing by-parts once more?

Comment: It seems that there are some problems with my steps, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one!  Consider

$$\int z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) \, dz = \int (z \Phi(z)) (z \phi(z)) \, dz \tag{1}$$
and choose $$u = z \Phi(z), \quad du = \Phi(z) + z \phi(z) \, dz, \\
dv = z \phi(z) \, dz, \quad v = -\phi(z). \tag{2}$$
Then $(1)$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
\int z^2 \Phi(z) \phi(z) \, dz
&= -z \Phi(z) \phi (z) + \int \Phi(z) \phi(z) + z \phi(z)^2 \, dz \\
&= -z \Phi(z) \phi(z) + \frac{\Phi(z)^2}{2} - \frac{\phi(z \sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} + C.
\tag{3}
\end{align}$$
All that remains is to evaluate the definite integral to obtain the expectation, noting that $\Phi(\infty) = 1$, and $\Phi(-\infty) = \phi(\pm\infty) = 0$:
$$\operatorname{E}[Z^2 \Phi(Z)] = \frac{1}{2}.$$
I have left out some of the computational details, but these should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really a tricky question.